# Would like Android virtual device to test 7" Samsung Tablet

Tags: android

I've found several posts with instructions similar to the following for adding Samsung device emulators:

> From the Android SDK and AVD Manager, select the following:
>   Available packages => Third Party Add-ons => Samsung Electronics add-ons => GALAXY Tab by Samsung Electronics., Android API 8, revision 1

I don't have a "Third Party Add-ons" selection in the SDK manager. Here's what I have:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

I'm guessing I need to add an add-on site to the ones I have:

[image]

Does anyone know how to find the 'Third Party Add-ons' packages? Specifically, the Samsung device emulators?